# first java program

Tags: java

Ok.. A very noob question.

This is my first attempt to write a class in java.

I created a project (Bank), a package (bank), and two classes `Account`, and `Driver`

So, my project looks like:

```
  Bank --> src-->bank --> Account.java --> Driver.java
```

Now `Driver.java` has `main`.

How do i call `Account.java` class from `Driver.java`

I have included package `bank` on both the files.

```
    Account myAccount = **Account**("foobar",12345); bold is where the error is.
```

It is not being able to find Account class.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Java you  create objects by using the keyword `new`

```
Account myAccount = new Account("foobar",12345);
```

As a sidenote:
If all your classes are in the same **package** you don't need to import them, but if you had `Account` in another package then you would have to import it by using

```
import path.to.package.Account;
```

Another sidenote as you continue to learn, not really related to this question:
If you were only to call a `static method` in `Account.java`, you wouldn't need to create an object. You would go like:

```
Account.mymethod()
```